# Filling in An Attribute Column with Values from a List in a standalone python script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have created an empty attribute column A via the following lines:

```
Layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/usr/Desktop/File.shp", "File", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(Layer)
lProvider = Layer.dataProvider()
lProvider.addAttributes( [ QgsField("Yield",QVariant.Double) ] )
```

I want to fill this column with the values : `t[0].Yield` from my list `t`.
I tried by doing the following ( it does not work):

```
updateMap = {}
iter = lProvider.getFeatures()
idYield = lProvider.fields().indexFromName('Yield')
for feature in iter: 
    Yield_fill = feature.attributes()[idYield] + t[0].Yield
    updateMap[ feature.id()] = {idYeild: Yield_fill}
lProvider.changeAttributeValues( updateMap )
```

Can you give me suggestions on how to edit the code above in order to accomplish what I want? I need to add information for many columns in this manner.